# FCM Notifications are not woking when app is background/closed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried many solutions but none of them are worked. I am able receive FCM notification when app is active, but not getting notification when app is background or killed. Trying from past 2 days. But no luck.

1.Enabled Remote Notifications

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let userDefaults = UserDefaultsData()
var notificationsDB: Tbl_Notifications?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DBFileURL.copyFile(fileName: "nActivity.sqlite")

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

    let savedData = userDefaults.findBool(key: Keys.UserDefaultsKey.IS_LOGGED_IN)

    if(savedData){
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dashboardViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboard") as!
        DashboardTabBarController
        window!.rootViewController = dashboardViewController
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isGranted, err) in
        if err != nil {
            //Something bad happend
        } else {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    ConnectToFCM()
}


func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func ConnectToFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("DCS: " + token)
    }

}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    ConnectToFCM()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
{
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        }
    }
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

    if fcmToken != "" {
        userDefaults.save(key: "fcmToken", value: fcmToken)
    }
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {

    print("backend data", remoteMessage.appData)
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

    let token = userDefaults.findString(key: "token")
    if token != "" {
        let notification: String = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("notification")]! as! String

        if let notificationData = notification.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                let dataDictonary: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: notificationData, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

                populateNotificationJSON(dataDictonary: dataDictonary)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

func populateNotificationJSON(dataDictonary: NSDictionary) {
    let commonParserInstance = CommonParser()

    let activityId: String = commonParserInstance.parse(dictionary: dataDictonary, key: "activityId", exceptionString: "")
    if activityId != "" {
        let message: String = commonParserInstance.parse(dictionary: dataDictonary, key: "message", exceptionString: "N/A")
        let time = getTime()

        notificationsDB = Tbl_Notifications()
        notificationsDB?.activityId = activityId
        notificationsDB?.message = message
        notificationsDB?.time = time

        let notificationModelDB = NotificationsDBModel.getInstance()
        notificationModelDB.open()

        let isInserted = notificationModelDB.retriveData(activityId: activityId)
        if isInserted {
            notificationModelDB.updateData(tbl_Notifications: notificationsDB!)
        } else {
            notificationModelDB.insertData(notificationsDB!)
        }

        notificationModelDB.close()

        showNotification(message: message)
    }
}

func showNotification(message: String) {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = message
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    //Time interval: Schedule a notification for a number of seconds later. For example to trigger in 1 seconds:
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}

func getTime() -> String {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy h:mm a "
    formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

    let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())

    return dateString
}
}
```

Below is Payload

```
[
  AnyHashable("from"): 425251449625, 
 AnyHashable("notification"): 
{
 "activityId":122,
 "activityNo":"122",
 "message":"The Activity No:122 is assigned by balaram balaram"
},
AnyHashable("content_available"): true, 
AnyHashable("mutable_content"): true, 
AnyHashable("priority"): high
]
```

Please help what I am missing?

Comment: Have you tired by setting priority to normal?

Comment: tried, none of the solutions are working.

Comment: can you please check after setting property shouldEstablishDirectChannel to false always.